# How to fix jqueryUI tolerance:intersect when sorting is animated

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an customized animated sortable, the only problem is the option

```
tolerance : "intersect"
```

Doesnt behave as expected. What i expect is, when an element is dragged over another one, and the overlapped element is overlapped +50% by the dragged one the sorting starts.

However this seems to be a bug in jqueryUI and it actually needs to be 100% overlapped with intersect instead of 50%.

Solutions i found on SO like in this thread dont work with my code, because I use clones to animate the elements while sorting.

[jQuery UI sortable tolerance option not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637095/jquery-ui-sortable-tolerance-option-not-working-as-expected)

How could I approach this problem given my situation and my code?

Are there known workarounds for this?

I realise this is the same question, but my situation is different and maybe there are better ways to solve this, then in the old question.

Here my Code:

http://jsbin.com/otoquh/19/edit

```
$("#original_items li").each(function(){
  var item = $(this);
  var item_clone = item.clone();
  item.data("clone", item_clone);
  var position = item.position();
  item_clone.css("left", position.left);
  item_clone.css("top", position.top);
  $("#cloned_items").append(item_clone);
});

$("#original_items").sortable({
  start: function(e, ui) {
    ui.helper.addClass("exclude-me");
    $("#original_items li:not(.exclude-me)").css("visibility", "hidden");
    ui.helper.data("clone").hide();

  },
stop: function(e, ui){
  $("#original_items li.exclude-me").each(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    var clone = item.data("clone");
    var position = item.position();
    clone.css("left", position.left);
    clone.css("top", position.top);
    clone.show();
    item.removeClass("exclude-me");

  });
  $("#original_items li").css("visibility", "visible");
},
  change: function(e, ui) {
    $("#original_items li:not(.exclude-me, .ui-sortable-placeholder)").each(function() {
      var item = $(this);
      var clone = item.data("clone");
      var position = item.position();
      clone.stop(true, false);
      clone.animate({
        left: position.left,
        top: position.top
      }, 500);

    });
  },
  revert: 500,
  axis: "y"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `tolerance` along with `cursorAt`.

I have made the following changes to your code:

```
$("#original_items").sortable({
  tolerance:"pointer",
  cursorAt:{ top: 50 },
  start: function(e, ui) {
    ui.helper.addClass("exclude-me");
    $("#original_items li:not(.exclude-me)").css("visibility", "hidden");
    ui.helper.data("clone").hide();

  },
stop: function(e, ui){
  $("#original_items li.exclude-me").each(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    var clone = item.data("clone");
    var position = item.position();
    clone.css("left", position.left);
    clone.css("top", position.top);
    clone.show();
    item.removeClass("exclude-me");

  });
  $("#original_items li").css("visibility", "visible");
},
  change: function(e, ui) {
    $("#original_items li:not(.exclude-me, .ui-sortable-placeholder)").each(function() {
      var item = $(this);
      var clone = item.data("clone");
      var position = item.position();
      clone.stop(true, false);
      clone.animate({
        left: position.left,
        top: position.top
      }, 500);

    });
  },
  revert: 500,
  axis: "y"
});
```

DEMO:  http://jsbin.com/otoquh/23/edit

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions!

---

LINKS:

- http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cursorAt

Comment: i will take a torough look at this, ty, only thing apparent at first glance, when you click an element at the bottom and start dragging the element jumps so the pointer is positioned at the middle of the element which looks jumpy...

Comment: thx for pointing that out, but it does more harm then good. what i really want is tolerance:intersect to behave as expected, independent of where the pointer is.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the cursor needs to be 50% past the top of the element (or left/right, etc).  That's why it seems like you have to drag it way past the element itself.

I, personally, prefer the `tolerance : "pointer"` option, which allows the element to replace the target element immediately as soon as the cursor enters the target element!  May or may not be what you're looking for.

https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-tolerance