# jQuery UI Sortable: tolerance "intersect" doesn't work as expected (bug #8342)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

9 days ago (at time of this writing) the following bug has been reopened:
[Sortable: Incorrect behaviour (or incorrect documentation) of sortable option tolerance: 'intersect'](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8342)

Unfortunately I can't wait for jQuery to fix this issue.

I have a single container with items that can be sorted vertically (all `<div>`s). These items have different heights (and none of those heights are predefined).

Is there a decent workaround available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a workaround myself, inspired by [dioslaska](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480191/dioslaska)'s solution to his own question here:
[jQuery UI sortable tolerance option not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10699339/1237411)

It works quite smoothly :)

Remove the `tolerance` option and use the following function as `sort` option:

```
function( e, ui ) {
    var container   = $( this ),
        placeholder = container.children( '.ui-sortable-placeholder:first' );

    var helpHeight  = ui.helper.outerHeight(),
        helpTop     = ui.position.top,
        helpBottom  = helpTop + helpHeight;

    container.children().each( function () {
        var item = $( this );

        if( !item.hasClass( 'ui-sortable-helper' ) && !item.hasClass( 'ui-sortable-placeholder' )) {
            var itemHeight = item.outerHeight(),
                itemTop    = item.position().top,
                itemBottom = itemTop + itemHeight;

            if(( helpTop > itemTop ) && ( helpTop < itemBottom )) {
                var tolerance = Math.min( helpHeight, itemHeight ) / 2,
                    distance  = helpTop - itemTop;

                if( distance < tolerance ) {
                    placeholder.insertBefore( item );
                    container.sortable( 'refreshPositions' );
                    return false;
                }

            } else if(( helpBottom < itemBottom ) && ( helpBottom > itemTop )) {
                var tolerance = Math.min( helpHeight, itemHeight ) / 2,
                    distance  = itemBottom - helpBottom;

                if( distance < tolerance ) {
                    placeholder.insertAfter( item );
                    container.sortable( 'refreshPositions' );
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up: sort is called very frequently so traversing all the container's children on every mouse move can be costly..