# jQuery UI sortable - overlapping by 50% doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

jQuery UI `sortable` plugin is intended to enable a group of DOM elements to be sortable. A nice demo is at official website [here](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

The [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-tolerance) provides `tolerance` option, and the description says:

> Specifies which mode to use for testing whether the item being moved is hovering over another item. Possible values: intersect, pointer

Furthermore, the description of intersect (which is default) states:

> intersect: The item overlaps the other item by at least 50%.

I expected, that if I drag one item, and move it over another item, it will detect that I'm reordering the items as soon as 50% of the height overlaps. But it doesn't seem to work this way :(. Even if you check the official [demo](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/), and you try to drag the 1st item over the 2nd item, you'll see that the 1st item has to be dragged for entire height, like 100% of its height, over the 2nd element, and only then the order of items is swapped.

Am I missing something? Is there any way for me as a programmer to force the plugin to work as I expect it to work? I wish the user to move the 1st item only 50% of its height down, in order for the plugin to detect overlapping and perform reordering.

Comment: Sorry for changing up the answer on you there. I switched the answer back to the way it was when you previously accepted it. I kept the extra information for anyone viewing this question in reference to grids (common problem) since I believe it is helpful and provides 50% overlap functionality (blocks are inserted, not swapped) so in that sense, it does work as shown in the fiddle. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer is:**

There's a [bug ticket](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8342) for this, so it seems like the only option is some form of workaround.

Here's [a workaround example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637095/jquery-ui-sortable-tolerance-option-not-working-as-expected) that uses a custom sort function, which seemed to answer your question better. I'll keep the below example as well for another approach to the problem.

...

**That covers the case with a single direction, but what if you want to implement a grid?**

Here's a workaround fiddle that I edited (Grid example w/ insert): [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2e4nwxnb/)

**Note**: *This doesn't swap blocks, it inserts them and pushes the rest back.*

Here's a snip of the javascript / jQuery code involved that mocks 50% coverage:

```
var height = $(".tab").height();
var height = $(".tab").width();

    $('#pointer').sortable({
        cursorAt: { top: height/2, left: width/2 },
        containment: 'parent',
        tolerance: 'pointer'
    });
```

Comment: I can see how it actually behaves. But I'm strongly convinced that the behavior is incorrect. tolerance:pointer should care about mouse cursor position. But tolerance:intersect should NOT, as far as I understand the DOCs. My question is, what can I do (as a programmer) to make my sortable elements behave the way I was expecting.

Comment: I've edited my question to better explain what is my question. I'm not asking as an user where to click. I am asking as a developer, what can I do to make it work my way for other users.

Comment: Thank you. The provided solution with cursorAt only moves the dragged item under the cursor so it is as if user dragged it at a specific position. Using top:0 is like if we clicked the item at the very top pixel. This is actually not fixing the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me here. I tested your fiddle and it does NOT work as I want. If I drag the first item regardless of the mouse cursor position, I must drag it for the entire height of the item down in order to swap with the second one. I want to drag it only by 50% of its height.

Comment: I do not undetstand why you edited your answer to some solution which doesn't work at all :) Your previous answer fixed the problem - providing custom 'sort' function to the jquery-ui plugin as mentioned in the workaround works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the widget's code you'll find:

```
if (this.options.tolerance === "pointer" || this._intersectsWithSides(item)) {
                    this._rearrange(event, item);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
```

So, due you specifie tolerance: "intersect", this._intersectsWithSides(item) is take it.

And function _intersectsWithSides(item) it's defined here:

```
_intersectsWithSides: function(item) {
        var isOverBottomHalf = this._isOverAxis(this.positionAbs.top +
 this.offset.click.top, item.top + (item.height/2), item.height),
            isOverRightHalf = this._isOverAxis(this.positionAbs.left + 
this.offset.click.left, item.left + (item.width/2), item.width),
            verticalDirection = this._getDragVerticalDirection(),
            horizontalDirection = this._getDragHorizontalDirection();
```

it take "item.height/2" and "item.width/2"

You can go with your on function and redefine this behaviour:

```
_myIntersectsWithSides: function(item) {
        var isOverBottomHalf = this._isOverAxis(this.positionAbs.top +
 this.offset.click.top, item.top + (item.height/5), item.height),
            isOverRightHalf = this._isOverAxis(this.positionAbs.left + 
this.offset.click.left, item.left + (item.width/5), item.width),
            verticalDirection = this._getDragVerticalDirection(),
            horizontalDirection = this._getDragHorizontalDirection();
```

And that give you 20% (100/5 instead of 100/2) of width and height.

The "50%" it's defined by code.-

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I can see that 50% is defined by code. But I complain that it does NOT work :] User has to drag the item 100% of height, not 50, to swap them.