# How to use jQuery UI Sortable to intersect properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Here's my attempt at animating jQuery UI Sortable:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YdMOXE

```
var startIndex, changeIndex, uiHeight;

$('ul').sortable({
    'placeholder': 'marker',
    start: function(e, ui) {

        startIndex = ui.placeholder.index();
        uiHeight = ui.item.outerHeight(true);//get offset incl margin

        ui.item.nextAll('li:not(.marker)').css({
            transform: 'translateY(' +uiHeight+ 'px)'
        });

        ui.placeholder.css({
            height: 0,
            padding: 0
        });
    },
    change: function(e, ui) {

        changeIndex = ui.placeholder.index();


        if (startIndex > changeIndex) {

            var slice = $('ul li').slice(changeIndex, $('ul li').length);

            slice.not('.ui-sortable-helper').each(function() {
                var item = $(this);
                item.css({
                    background:'lightcoral',
                    transform: 'translateY(' +uiHeight+ 'px)'
                });
            });

        } else if (startIndex < changeIndex) {

            var slice = $('ul li').slice(startIndex, changeIndex);

            slice.not('.ui-sortable-helper').each(function() {
                var item = $(this);
                item.css({
                    background: 'lightgreen',
                    transform: 'translateY(0px)'
                });
            });
        }

        startIndex = changeIndex
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        $('.ui-sortable-handle').css({
            background: 'lightblue',
            transform: 'translateY(0)'
        })
    }
});
```

Unfortunately it does not work reliably with `tolerance: intersect`. (sorting to change when `50%` of the element is overlapping). It seems to want to sort only via pointer location. Attached is a video to show this. https://gfycat.com/WatchfulPresentHedgehog

How do I get this to work correctly with intersect?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31817876/9276329) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10637095/9276329) questions for more info about this issue.

Comment: Harry, why I do not get any response from you? I wrote for you a good answer. If you are satisfied with my answer then mark my answer as accepted, please.

Comment: @MunimMunna actually answered my question but he did not post an answer so I ended up having noone to accept.

Comment: @Bharata secondly your answer still doesn't fix it nor does it go along with what I requested which was to use 'intersect' instead of 'pointer'. But despite that I'm still grateful for your help. <3

Comment: @Harry, I have tested now the workarounds (from **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10699339/9801830)** (I have corrected it for vertical using) and from **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13389567/9801830)**) which was linked in Munim Munna comment and both workarounds do not work correctly (very very buggy). My workaround has best result. And what do you use now? Or you do not use this anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see **[the bug #8342](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8342)**

> Sortable: Incorrect behaviour (or incorrect documentation) of sortable option `tolerance: 'intersect'`

I have tested now workarounds (from **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10699339/9801830)** (I have corrected it for vertical using) and from **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13389567/9801830)**) which were linked in Munim Munna comment and both workarounds do not work correctly (very very buggy).

### Workaround with `tolerance: 'pointer'`

You have to set `tolerance: 'pointer'` along with `cursorAt: {top: height/2, left: width/2}` (the half size from the width and height of your draggable element).

`tolerance : 'pointer'` option allows the element to replace the target element immediately as soon as the cursor enters the target element. By default it was setted to `tolerance : 'intersect'` which means that the item overlaps the other item by at least 50%. But unfortunately there is a bug for this option (see the top of my answer).

Try also to use it with and without `cursorAt` option or to change the value. This option moves the sorting element or helper so the cursor always appears to drag from the same position. Coordinates can be given as a hash using a combination of one or two keys: `{top, left, right, bottom}`.

Here is the documentation for **[`tolerance` option](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-tolerance)** and for **[`cursorAt` option](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cursorAt)**.

**Update from 29.01.2019**

I have fixed some bugs from jQuery UI Sortable: on dragging from last item if after it it has not enough space for moving. I have fixed this bug with adding this code:

```
<div style="clear: both; line-height: 500px">&nbsp;</div>
```

directly after sortable element.

```js
var startIndex, changeIndex, uiHeight,
    bRect = $("ul li")[0].getBoundingClientRect(),
    width = bRect.right - bRect.left,
    height = bRect.bottom - bRect.top;

$('ul').sortable(
{
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    cursorAt: {top: height/2, left: width/2}, //try to use it with and without this option
    'placeholder': 'marker',
    start: function(e, ui)
    {
        startIndex = ui.placeholder.index();
        uiHeight = ui.item.outerHeight(true); //get offset incl margin

        ui.item.nextAll('li:not(.marker)').css({
            transform: 'translateY(' + uiHeight + 'px)'
        });
        ui.placeholder.css({height:0, padding:0});
    },

    change: function(e, ui)
    {
        changeIndex = ui.placeholder.index();

        if(startIndex > changeIndex)
        {
            var slice = $('ul li').slice(changeIndex, $('ul li').length);

            slice.not('.ui-sortable-helper').each(function()
            {
                var item = $(this);
                item.css({
                    background:'lightcoral',
                    transform: 'translateY(' +uiHeight+ 'px)'
                });
            });
        }
        else if(startIndex < changeIndex)
        {
            var slice = $('ul li').slice(startIndex, changeIndex);
            slice.not('.ui-sortable-helper').each(function()
            {
                var item = $(this);
                item.css({
                    background: 'lightgreen',
                    transform: 'translateY(0px)'
                });
            });
        }

        startIndex = changeIndex
    },

    stop: function(e, ui)
    {
        $('.ui-sortable-handle').css({
            background: 'lightblue',
            transform: 'translateY(0)'
        })
    }
});
```

```css
body{color:white; font-family:Helveticasans-serif; padding:10px}
ul{float:left; width:300px; border-radius:6px}
ul:after{clear:both; content:''; display:table}
li
{
    background: lightblue;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 80px 6px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 5px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform .2s
}
.marker{opacity:0.0; transition:.2s height}
.ui-sortable-helper{transform:scale(.9)}
```

```html
<br><br>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
<!--
Fixing some bugs from jQuery UI Sortable:
on dragging from last item if after it
it has not enough space for moving
-->
<div style="clear: both; line-height: 500px">&nbsp;</div>
<!--END of Fixing bugs-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

It is more useful to see this code snippet in full page (use the link at top of the right from snippet).

Comment: The `charAt` position should be `{top:90}` as the boxes are 178px in height.

Comment: @MunimMunna, thank you! I had in my head the 50% and then wrote this size istead of calculation. I have corrected it. :-)

Comment: It's buggy, the first time you drag it top or bottom it works, but then it stops working.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy, thank you! I have checked it – it seems that jQuery UI Sortable has some bugs. But it is not always – only for the short time. I have checked it on **[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YBzgXL)** and on my local PC and there it is the same.

Comment: @MunimMunna, now I have fixed all the bugs and sizes.

Comment: Very nice, it does appear very smooth now, I will look into it later to see how you did it.